# How to create a popup in a widget call back function in ipywidgets?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, jupyter, ipywidgets

Using `ipywidgets` 7.5.1 and `python` 3.6.9 in a jupyterlab environment (version 1.2.3) I have created the following complete test code:

```
from ipywidgets import widgets
from IPython.display import HTML,Javascript, display

def popup(text):
    display(HTML("<script>alert('{}');</script>".format(text)))

class Test:

    def __init__(self):        
        self.button = widgets.Button(description='TestButton')
        self.button.on_click(self.click) 
        display(self.button)

    def click(self,args):           
        popup("test2")   

popup("test1")          
login = Test()
```

When running this code I get a popup with the text `test1` which I expect, but when I click on the button and the callback function is executed I expected to have another popup with the text `test2`, but nothing happens. There is no other popup.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I can see the 2nd pop up fine when I click the button. with python 3.6, ipywidgets 7.4.2 jupyter notebook and Chrome 80.0.3987.87.

Comment: Using Google Colaboratory, I don't see either popup.

Answer (score 0):

With Jupyter Lab I see the first popup but on clicking, the second doesn't pop up and just adds a blank line to the log.

```
    $ jupyter --version                                                                    
    jupyter core     : 4.6.3                                                                                                                
    jupyter-notebook : 6.1.3                                                                                                
    qtconsole        : not installed                                                                                            
    ipython          : 7.17.0                                                                                               
    ipykernel        : 5.3.4                                                                                                
    jupyter client   : 6.1.6                                                                                                
    jupyter lab      : 2.2.8                                                                                                
    nbconvert        : 5.6.1                                                                                                
    ipywidgets       : 7.5.1                                                                                                
    nbformat         : 5.0.7                                                                                                
    traitlets        : 4.3.3
```

Comment: Please, explain your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Put these scripts inside the function called by the widgets

```
from IPython.display import HTML,Javascript, display
display(Javascript("""
    require(
        ["base/js/dialog"], 
        function(dialog) {
            dialog.modal({
                title: 'Hello world',
                body: 'Hi, lorem ipsum and such',
                buttons: {
                    'kthxbye': {}}
            });
        }
    );
```

"""))

Comment: What is this `require`? Can you show a bit of full code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to answer this question, but your code pushed me in the right direction when I was trying to accomplish the same, so I hope this helps everyone else.

Short answer: You need to provide an `Output` for your javascript. This minimal example does the trick and you can click the button multiple times (however your browser might ask you if you want to block additional dialogs after the first time)

```
from ipywidgets import widgets
from IPython.display import HTML, display, clear_output

notify_output = widgets.Output()
display(notify_output)
```

You can put this anywhere in your notebook, as long as you have called `display(notify_output)` before you call `popup()` for the first time.

```
@notify_output.capture()
def popup(text):
    clear_output()
    display(HTML("<script>alert('{}');</script>".format(text)))

def clickme(b):
    popup('Hello World!')

btn_clickme = widgets.Button(description='Click me!')
btn_clickme.on_click(clickme)

display(btn_clickme)
```

**Edit:** The (slightly) better way to do this is to use the `Javascript` widget instead of `HTML`:

```py
from ipywidgets import widgets
from IPython.display import Javascript, display, clear_output
```

```py
@notify_output.capture()
def popup(text):
    clear_output()
    display(Javascript("alert('{}')".format(text)))
```

Further information on jupyter's `Output` widget can be found in the [Jupyter Widgets documentation](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20List.html#Output).

The reason your code only works once is because jupyter writes the output of a cell to the main window when the cell is executed. If you execute a function which generates displayable output multiple times, that output lands in the log, but javascript is not executed there (I guess for security reasons). However, if you use an `Output` *widget* to capture the output of your function, this also works if you execute it multiple times. I added a call to `clear_output` so you don't "fill up" your output with unnecessary `<script>` tags. Not that you would notice, as these are not rendered.

Comment: Thanks for adding this. There's a lot of old code out there that isn't handling the output right, or at least not in line with current approaches. The usual telling characteristic is when it gets sent to the 'log' console. Sometimes people miss that happening if they aren't using JupyterLab or not as familiar with JupyterLab. The underlying machinery for the next iteration of the document-centric Jupyter Notebook  will see be more JupyterLab-like and so those not moving towards the modern conventions are going to be out of luck.